# (GWT) How to fill-in color on a selected row in a table?

Tags: gwt

I have a table where the user clicks a check box to select a row.

I want to have it where the user clocks on the row of interest and have that row fill in with a colored background. How do I go about this in GWT?

EDIT: I would like to know how this can be achieved using the FlexTable. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manipulate the row style on a click action add a `ClickHandler` to the FlexTable object. In the `onClick(ClickEvent)` you can get the cell clicked via the FlexTable method `getCellForEvent(ClickEvent)`. The Cell returned contains information on the row (and column) number that was clicked. Via `getRowFormatter().getElement()` you can get the element of the row and add a stylename to the row, to add color or directly in code set the color on the row in code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a celltable. 
Following is an example:
http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable

In celltables, when you click a cell, the entire row gets highlighted. You can change the highlighted color with css to your desire.

Try the following code:

```
public class CellTableExample implements EntryPoint {

    private static class Contact {
        private String address; 
        private String name;

        public Contact(String name, String address) {
            super();
            this.address = address; 
            this.name = name; 
        } 
    }

    // The list of data to display.
      private static List<Contact> CONTACTS = Arrays.asList(
        new Contact("John", "123 Fourth Road asdf asdf asdfasdf"),
        new Contact("Mary", "222 Lancer Lane")

      );

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        CellTable<Contact> table = new CellTable<Contact>(); 

        //address column
        TextColumn<Contact> addressColumn = new TextColumn<Contact>(){
            @Override
            public String getValue(Contact contact) {
                return contact.address;
            }
        };

        //name column
        TextColumn<Contact> nameColumn = new TextColumn<Contact>(){
            @Override
            public String getValue(Contact contact) {
                return contact.name;
            }
        };

        // Add the columns.
        table.addColumn(nameColumn, "Name");
        table.addColumn(addressColumn, "Address");

        table.setRowCount(CONTACTS.size(), true);
        table.setRowData(0, CONTACTS);

        RootPanel.get().add(table); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good. But I want to know how it can be achieved with use of FlexTables? My code is kind of big so trying to switch to cell table will be difficult and tedious.